# Need to know how to write a condition in pl/sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIKcy.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31jE8.jpg)I have a Table-A which contains columns: ID, original ID and unique Id,percentage1,percentage2

Table-B which contains the columns:All IDs, percentage

My requirement:
Compare the ID column in table A with the all ids column in table B.If both the IDs are equal then the respective percentage in table B should be inserted in table A percentage1 column.if Ids are not equal then it should insert NA in the percentage 1 column.

How to check this condition using procedure and cursors in pl/sql

Comment: Which database do you use? If it is MySQL, then it isn't PL/SQL (because it belongs to Oracle) and vice versa. As of your question, could you post some sample data and desired result?

Comment: I am using the PL/SQL. I have included the sample data and desired results into an image and attached to the question. Kindly refer

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/31jE8.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sample data (I believe there's a typo in text; it talks about A12345, while table_a contains A12344):

```
SQL> select * from table_a;

ID     ORIGIN UNIQUE PERCENTAGE1 PERCENTAGE2
------ ------ ------ ----------- -----------
A12345 A00112 A11001
B45678 B00223 B11001
C34567 C00332 C11001

SQL> select * from table_b;

ALL_ID PERCENTAGE
------ ----------
A12345          1
B45678          6
A00112         13
B00223         15
```

Use `merge` to set percentage columns' values:

```
SQL> merge into table_a a
  2  using table_b b
  3  on (a.id = b.all_id)
  4  when matched then update set
  5    a.percentage1 = b.percentage;

2 rows merged.

SQL> merge into table_a a
  2  using table_b b
  3  on (a.original_id = b.all_id)
  4  when matched then update set
  5    a.percentage2 = b.percentage;

2 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table_a;

ID     ORIGIN UNIQUE PERCENTAGE1 PERCENTAGE2
------ ------ ------ ----------- -----------
A12345 A00112 A11001           1          13
B45678 B00223 B11001           6          15
C34567 C00332 C11001

SQL>
```

Comment: What about the unmatched records? If id in table A doesn't match with all ids in table B then it should display 'NA' in the percentage1 column. Similarly if original id in table A doesn't match with all_id in table B it should display 'NA' in the percentage 2 column

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIKcy.jpg

Comment: MERGE won't touch unmatched records. As of "NA", that's a **string**. Percentage is, on the other hand, a **number**. You can't put a string into a NUMBER datatype column, so workaround is to display "NA" when selecting rows from the table (use NVL function for that), or - a worse option - change percentage's datatype to VARCHAR2.